# Regex matching on dictionary keys

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, key, normalization

Imagine we have a dictionary: `{'Hello World': value1, 'Testing': value2}`

Now we need to look up a word in the dictionary. The key K will need to exactly match 'Hello World' or 'Testing', to use.

So let our `text = 'hello     world'` we still want this to return `value1`

So how do we handle this regex matching of text to keys? Ideally we don't want to iterate through the dictionary

Edit: Spacing aspect is just a simple example. The text may change in case, be a combination of numbers and letters we want to match. We would usually use a regex pattern

Comment: Use `" ".join(text.split()).title()`?

Comment: Thanks, but what about more complex regex patterns? It may not be just a spacing issue

Comment: Please add at least one expected input/output to your question ... I'm not sure what you need exactly ..!

Comment: Kind of completely defeats the purpose of using a dict, where is your data coming from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't believe it does. I'm doing a fast search and replace without for loops, where by when there is a match the match.group() is returning a cleaner word than that in the dictionary keys

Comment: @redrubia, if you have to do a worst case  `O(n)` scan every time  then you have a quadratic algorithm, for every word in your input list you have to go over at worst every key in your dict

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. You should give more examples of input and desired output, otherwise zondo's comment answers your question.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0455/

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is pretty much defeating the efficiency of `dict`s, so you're probably better off making your own `dict`-like class. Here's a simple example:

```
from re import search, I

class RegexMap(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._items = dict(*args, **kwargs)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        for regex in self._items.keys():
            if search(regex, key, I):
                return self._items[regex]
        raise KeyError
```

Usage:

```
>>> rm = RegexMap({'\s*hello\s*world\s*':1, '\s*foo\s*bar\s*':2})
>>> rm['Hello World']
1
>>> rm['foobar']
2
>>> rm['baz']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    rm['baz']
  File "C:\Users\dmurphy\Documents\python\_t.py", line 10, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError
KeyError
>>>
```

From there, you can add more `dict` functionality. See the [Data Model docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types).

It does break your "no iteration" clause, but I'm not sure there's any way around that if you want to generalize to regexes.

Comment: Maybe because OP said he doesn't want to iterate over the keys, and your solution does exactly that? But I agree there seems to be no way around some kind of iteration in his case.

Comment: @gill Fair enough, I missed that all 3 times I read it. He did say "ideally", though, and I'm not sure there's a way around it.

Comment: Sure he did. But looks like if OP didn't have this (I think) unreachable ideal then we wouldn't have this question. ps. I didn't downvote you :)

Comment: @gill Oh, I know. The downvoters don't tend to stick around to explain themselves if they don't leave a comment immediately.

Comment: ^^ I appreciate all input, but please don't assume I'm male.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like,

```
>>> d = {'Hello World': 'value1', 'Testing': 'value2'}
>>> text = 'hello     world'
>>> key = next(x for x in (re.search(r'(?i)' + re.sub(r'(\s)+', r'\1', text.strip()), i) for i in d.keys()) if x).group()
>>> d[key]
'value1'
```

Answer (score 0):

To help the lookup you could either sort and bisect to find where to start looking to narrow down the lookups breaking when you find a match or the current key is > that what you are looking fo.

```
from bisect import bisect_left

d = {'Hello World': "value1", 'Testing': "value2"}

items = sorted([(k.lstrip().lower(),v) for k, v in d.items()])

text = 'hello     world'
ind = bisect_left(items,(text.lower(),), hi=len(items) - 1)
# use items[ind]
```

Or create a mapping using the first couple of letters of each key:

```
from collections import defaultdict
lookup_mapping = defaultdict(list)

for k in d:
    lookup_mapping[k[:2].lower().lstrip()].append(k)

poss =  lookup_mapping[text[:2].lower().lstrip()]
```

You can either use a regex to find the match or normalize the data by slitting, stripping etc.. it completely depends on what the input can look like but by grouping you can at least reduce the amount of comparisons you have to make.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider normalizing the keys in your dict. Using python's [string.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function with no delimiter will remove all whitespace.

```
def normalize(word):
    return " ".join(word.split()).lower()
d = {'Hello World': 'value1', 'Testing': 'value2'}
d = {normalize(k): v for k, v in d.items()} 
print(d)
>>> {'hello world': 'value1', 'testing': 'value2'}
text = 'hello     world'
d[normalize(text)]
>>> 'value1'
```

Comment: What if you have the words `"cat dog"` and `"catd og"`?

Comment: those would both be normalized to "catdog"

Comment: That's my point, your solution does not work. If your original dictionary is `d = {"Cat Dog": "value1", "Catd Og": "value2"}`, you just lose one of them.

Comment: Ah I see- then better to use a space in the join:

    d = {" ".join(k.split()).lower(): v for k, v in d.items()}

This would leave:

   d =  {'cat dog': 'value1', 'catd og': 'value2'}